# how to get video format data from api in flutter

Tags: flutter

i am looking to continuously receive FLV video data from an API and display it as a video in a Flutter UI. Despite trying various packages like video_player and flutter_vlc_player, you're encountering difficulties in playing the data.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: var uri = Uri.parse("http://128.199.21.17:3333/video/005766065885-1");
 HttpClientRequest request = await client.getUrl(uri);
HttpClientResponse response = await request.close();if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final stringData = await response.transform(utf8.decoder).join();
      var body = json.decode(stringData);
      _controller = VideoPlayerController.network(body)
        ..initialize().then((_) {
            setState(() {
            _isVideoLoaded = true;
          });
        });
    

      _controller.setLooping(true);
      _controller.setVolume(0.0);
    }

Comment: i get in api response as a video and video format is .flv and i want to display in UI and main thing is data continuosly comes from api and i want to display it and functionality like live streaming